# Finding characters with spaces

Tags: javascript, regex

I was trying last week to find parts of a text containing specific words delimited by punctuation characters. That works well.

```
[^.?!:]*\b(why|how)\b[^.?!]*[.?!]
```

On the following sentence `"How did you do it? bla bla bla! why did you do it?"`, it's giving me the following output :

```
"How did you do it?"
"why did you do it?"
```

Now I am trying to add the hyphen character : I want to detect if there is an hyphen with spaces around (a new sentence delimiter):

```
"The man went walking upstairs - why was he there?
```

That would return me : `"why was he there?"`

It would follow the following rules:

```
hello - bye -> this would be the only one to be matched
hello-bye -> not matched
hello -bye -> not matched
hello- bye -> not matched
```

Using the negation, I tried to add that part :

```
[^.?!:\\s\\-\\s] => ignore everything that ends with a "." or a "?" or a "!" or a ":" or a " - "
```

I doesn't work, but as I am pretty bad using regex, I am probably missing something obvious.

```
var regex = /[^.?!:\\s\\-\\s]*\b(why|how)\b[^.?!]*[.?!]/igm
var text = "Here I am - why did you want to see me?"

var match;

while ((match = regex.exec(text)) != null) {
    console.log(match);
}
```

Output :

```
Here I am - why did you want to see me?
```

Expected output :

```
why did you want to see me?
```

Comment: *I doesn't work* - do you get any errors? Do you use it as `RegExp("[^.?!:\\s\\-\\s]")` or `/[^.?!:\\s\\-\\s]/`? You might want to have a look at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32740108/js-regex-allowing-incorrect-characters

Comment: Are you sure that the text contains a negative sign and not a visually similar character? Did you check the code of the character?

Comment: See https://regex101.com/r/MV6Szc/1 - I cannot repro. You have  a problem with backslashes.

Comment: I just edited my question and added an example of the output I have.

Comment: Ok, there are 2 issues: 1) backslashes (use single inside a regex literal, double in constructor) and 2) the sequence inside a character class (replace `[^.?!:\\s\\-\\s]` with `(?:(?!\\s-\\s)[^.?!:])*`).

Comment: I edited it again, added the part of code

Comment: Sorry, I must rush now, `var regex = /(?:(?!\s-\s)[^.?!:])*\b(why|how)\b[^.?!]*[.?!]/igm` is close, but includes the hyphen.

Comment: Yay, thank you! When you have time, add the answer below, I'll accept it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are two issues that I see:

- backslashes (use single inside a regex literal, double in constructor) and
- Sequence is used inside a character class (replace `[^.?!:\s\-\s]` with `(?:(?!\s-\s)[^.?!:])*)`.

You may use

```
var regex = /(?:(?!\s-\s)[^.?!:])*\b((?:why|how)\b[^.?!]*)[.?!]/ig
```

where `(?:(?!\s-\s)[^.?!:])*` is a [**tempered greedy token**](http://www.rexegg.com/regex-quantifiers.html#tempered_greed) matching any character other than `^.?!:` that is not starting a `whitespace`+`-`+`whitespace` pattern.

```js
var regex = /(?:(?!\s-\s)[^.?!:])*\b((?:why|where|pourquoi|how)\b[^.?!]*)[.?!]/ig;
var text = "L'Inde a déjà acheté nos rafales, pourquoi la France ne le -dirait-elle pas ?";
var match;
while ((match = regex.exec(text)) != null) {
    console.log(match[1]);
}
```

Comment: Just noticed that if a sentence contains two "-", the sentence will be cut at the 2nd occurence. Example : "I am there - where are-you?" will give the output "-you"

Comment: I could not repro in the regex site - https://regex101.com/r/qZFKHs/3. I also added a whole snippet here. Please show the exact text you pass.

Comment: "L'Inde a déjà acheté nos rafales, pourquoi la France ne le -dirait-elle pas ?" is a sentence that would give the following output -> "dirait-elle pas ?"

Comment: See my updated snippet, no split is expected since there is no `-` enclosed with spaces, and no split occurs. What is the regex you are using?

Comment: It was apparently my bad, I added a "-" at the end of the negation which was leading me to the wrong output ([^.?!:-]). I managed to fix that by deleting it, and replace the - at the beginning of the sentence, just as you did. Thanks for the help!

Comment: I [readjusted the capturing groups](https://regex101.com/r/qZFKHs/4) to avoid the additional replace operation.

Answer (score 1):

`[   ]` is always a character class, which means that at one position, you can match *one* character. The "negation" in your example is in fact probably not even doing what you thing it does.

What you probably want to match is *either the beginning of a string, the end of a sentence, or a dash with two spaces around*, so just replace it with `(^|[.?!]| - )\b((why|how)...etc)`. You will need some post processing of the result, as JavaScript does not support look-behind assertions as far as I know.

Answer (score 1):

Given your 4 examples, this works.

```
/\s-\s(\w*)/g
```

Test it here - https://regex101.com/r/YQhRBI/1

I'm matching ANY character within the *question* portion.  If you want to match specific key words, you'd swap the `(\w*)` with `([why|how|who|what|where|when])`

I think if you had a paragraph, you'd have to be sure to find a way to terminate the *answer* portion with a specific delimiter.  If this was more along the lines of a *question/answer* per new line, then you'd need only to end the regex with an end-of-line anchor.

Comment: This is accurate save for the `[` and `]` sneaking into your question words group, making it a rather overlong character group equivalent to `[why|oatern]`.